# Break points are not active in VS2005

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints, windows-mobile-6

I have a windows mobile project in VS2005. Initially I could not get any breakpoints to enable on windows mobile 6 device but they worked on PocketPC2003 Emulator. It's a new computer at work and after a while I realised I had no installed any SDK's beyond 2003. Having now installed SDK's for windows mobile 5.0 6.0 and 6.5.3 I now have SOME of my breakpoints active.

My solution consists of a main application under which there are a few screens and associated code. There are also a series of other classes each of which compiles to a separate DLL. It seems the issue I have is that any breakpoints in these separate classes 
work perfectly now. However any breakpoints in the main application class give an error "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." I've tried a number of things including deleting the bin\debug and obj folders to clear old debug information. The PBD files appear to be created ok for the exe files as well as the class DLL's but only the Dll's work correctly in debug.

Any ideas guys. I really have to get this working as it needs to work on a device not just an emulator. I have an external DLL I need to use as part of testing that is very specific to a brand and model range of hardware. I wont explain why here, just suffice it to say I really need to get this sorted.

I'm still learning VS2005 So please be specific with suggestions as I might not yet know where to locate certain functionality.

I should probably add it works fine in windows mobile 5.0 emulator but I don't have a windows mobile 5 device to test with

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know exactly what I did but it is now working. I read an article on here about enabling the module tab in the debug menu and after doing that it worked however I had done a couple of other things prior to doing that and hadn't tested it so not sure which it was that fixed it.